# Getting "publickey: no more keys to try" error with Eclipse Git Integration

Tags: git, eclipse, ssh, egit

Eclipse IDE gives this error when trying to push a commit into a gitlab repository:

```
Can't connect to any repository: git@gitlab.com:redacted/name.git (git@gitlab.com:redacted/name.git: Cannot log in at gitlab.com:22
publickey: trying ssh-rsa key SHA256:em+KoqJtfIysPRvugiGRHI702T+k4waTv9rh19U5TmM from SSH agent with signature type rsa-sha2-512
publickey: trying ssh-rsa key ~/.ssh/id_rsa with signature type rsa-sha2-512
publickey: trying ssh-rsa key ~/.ssh/id_rsa with signature type rsa-sha2-512
publickey: no more keys to try)
```

My key pair for gitlab access is stored under the name `gitlab` and `gitlab.pub`. And if I understood the error message correctly, Eclipse did not find these files and failed to authenticate with the server. I had already done `ssh-add gitlab` and `ssh -T git@gitlab.com` works as expected. Git CLI is also able to push local changes. The field "private keys" in my Eclipse IDE configuration under General>Network Configuration>SSH2 also has `gitlab` included. How should I fix this?

Comment: All keys in _General > Network Configurations > SSH2_ tab _General_ including your `gitlab` key have been tried but none worked. `rsa-sha2-512` means a key length of only 512. Nowadays, longer keys are commonly required, which might be the cause here.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your response lead me to the right direction and ultimately helped me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After some additional testing. I can conclude that eclipse is having trouble with large RSA keys. Using a new key length of 4096 solves the issue.

Comment: Large RSA keys works fine for me in Eclipse. It's the server that rejects short keys for security reasons, in your case a key of the length 512.